# Error processing request stream. The type name '<type name>' is not valid

Tags: c#, wcf, ef-code-first, odata

i am building an application with Entity framework 5.0 code first and WCF Data services 5.0

i have Business layer , data service layer and a domain  layer,

In the domain layer i have all the POCO entities (SomeContext)which represent database table and other models, this project i got dbcontext as well. which is referenced in the data service layer for DataService

I have created context reference using datasvcutil.exe in side dataservice layer and  written all the service call in the data service call. which is called from business layer.

On saving i am getting following error 
Error processing request stream. The type name '.DataService.Carrier' is not valid.

below is my save method (this method inside DataServiceContext)

```
  public DataServiceResponse SaveCarriers(Carrier carrier)
        {
            this.AddToCarriers(carrier);
            return SaveChanges();
        }
```

what i am missing? can any one guide me?

Thank you

Comment: I have fixed my self by creating service reference within business layer and creating all the save methods withing the context. But i wanted database related task to handle in separate layer. time being it works, i am looking for better solution, any idea are welcome.